# Can different data series be used in the same column (Excel, Stacked Bar Chart, Multi-Category)

Tags: excel, bar-chart, stacked-chart

Good day.

My data looks like this (Please assume it is correct):

[image]

My graph (Stacked Column) from this data does not show the Multi-Category("Car Classes") information:

[image]

This is what the result should look like (Manually edited in Paint):

[image]

I have tried and failed in many different ways to get this data to show.
Please help.

Comment: Is that screenshot showing your current chart attempt? If this is not your desired chart, can you please explain what the desired chart should look like? Mock it up with the drawing tools, then post a screenshot of the desired chart and explain how it relates to your data sample. You may need to use a special data layout to achieve the results that you want.

Comment: And what do you mean with "quick easy points" in the question title??

Comment: Thanks I took your advice. Here is what the result should look like included. Sorry "quick easy points" is maybe a too direct translation into English from my first language. It just means this should be a quick solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a different data layout for the chart you desire. In order to have the A and B as series, it's easiest to put the values in their own columns. You may want to omit the line with the total to 100 ( it just doesn't add anything useful to the chart).

You may want to create a helper table for the chart layout. This can be done on a different sheet, using formulas to pull the data from the original source.

Use a data layout like below, select the data, insert a horizontal 100% bar chart and switch rows/columns.

[image]